# Лексическая сочетаемость

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

Подскажите, будьте добры, какое слово лучше лексически сочетается со словом "обход": произвести обход корабля, совершить обход корабля, осуществить обход корабля, сделать обход корабля

Answer (score 1):

Обычно используются сочетания ***совершить обход*** или ***сделать обход,***  например:

Он встал и **совершил ночной обход** квартиры, обследовал дом, в котором прожил почти двадцать лет.  [Людмила Улицкая. 2000]

В десять часов вечера я **делаю последний обход**.[Ю. О. Домбровский. (1943-1958)]

***Произвести обход*** ― такой вариант также возможен,  это более **официальный** стиль. ПРОИЗВЕСТИ, св. 1. что. Сделать, совершить; провести.

Наименее удачным кажется сочетание ***осуществить обход***. ОСУЩЕСТВИТЬ,  св. что. Привести в исполнение, воплотить в действительность